# Equivalent de « Quand on a goûté au caviar, c'est difficile de retourner au pâté ! »

Tags: expressions, synonymes, humour

Connaissez-vous des équivalents de cette expression qui permettent d’*illustrer* ce point (si possible avec humour) :

> Quand on a expérimenté quelque chose de bien, il est difficile de revenir à quelque chose de moins bien.

Ou (merci à cl-r)

> Quand on a goûté/essayé à …, il est difficile de s’en passer.

L'expression citée ci-dessus se focalise sur le prix. Je cherche une expression avec une connotation moins matérialiste.

Edit : je cherche une expression qui permettrait de comparer des expériences, "après avoir fait cette expérience (incroyable), celle-ci (qui est bien, mais pas incroyable) parait un peu moins bien.

Comment: Il semble y avoir énormément de réponses *possible* à cette question, qui ne s'adaptera qu'à des contextes particuliers. Pouvez-vous donner le contexte dans lequel vous voulez utiliser cette expression ?

Comment: La différence entre Petrossian et Hénaff n'est pas uniquement tarifaire!

Comment: Il y a un proverbe, qui a donné un titre de film, sur cette idée: _Plus on s'élève et plus dure sera la chute_. Ça me fait aussi penser au conte du pêcheur et sa femme des frères Grimm et bien sûr à l'histoire d'Icare.

Comment: "L'expression citée ci-dessus se focalise sur le prix", c'est faux. Même s'il y a une connotation luxieuse avec la réference au caviar, ce dernier n'en est pas moins plus rafiné que le pâté et ce, en dehors de toutes considérations pécuniaires.

Comment: "après avoir fait cette expérience (incroyable), celle-ci (qui est bien, mais pas incroyable) parait un peu moins bien." => "Je m'en fous comme de mes premières règles."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La structure habituelle de la phrase  est : *Quand on a goûté/essayé à …, il est difficile de s’en passer.*

> Quel malheur de revenir au pain noir quand on a goûté au pain blanc.

... signe que l’on s’est échappé d'une 'misère' un moment bien trop court.

> Bigre, une deux chevaux après une Rolls Royce, quelle chute !
>
> Quel gadin ! Un roman à l'eau de rose après une idylle parfaite !
>
> Du pipeau après le Grand Orchestre de Paris, quel dénuement !
>
> L'odeur du fennec après celle des roses d’Ispahan, c'est rude !
>
> C'est un vrai plaisir de manger du foie de morue après un chocolat noir !
>
> Reprendre la bure après la soie, ça gratte !

---

*Complément, suite aux commentaires*

> Escalader la dune du Pilat après le Mont-Blanc, c'est faire les deux sommets les plus hauts d'Europe !
>
> Finir *"Amiral de la flotte du bassin du jardin du Luxembourg de Paris"*, après trois Transat en solitaire, quelle carrière !
>
> G.O. l'été, olé-olé ! Barman l'hiver... monde à l'envers.

Comment: Assez complexe comme question, puisqu'elle demande quelque chose de non matérialiste, or la phrase que vous proposez est beaucoup plus agréable à l'oreille mais reste néanmoins matérialiste. Je me demande d'ailleurs si il est possible d'enlever la notion de matérialisme dans cette expression.

Comment: @GautierC -- La référence au pain noir est le symbole de la misère et des luttes du XIXe siècle.

Comment: d'accord ! replacé dans le contexte, je comprend mieux ! :) Je retire donc mon hypothèse ;)

Comment: cl-r merci pour tes réponses (j'ai bien aimé la dernière !). Mais je cherche une expression qui permettrait de comparer des expériences, "après avoir fait cette expérience (incroyable), celle-ci (qui est bien, mais pas incroyable) parait un peu moins bien. J'ai pu updater ma question grâce à toi.

Comment: @cl-r (Je te remercie de ne pas supprimer tes réponses, des équivalents d'expression sont toujours précieux. Plus il y en a, mieux c'est).

Comment: @Lisa -- Pour un début de suite...